# Computing the quotient of SL(2,Z) by its commutator subgroup

Tags: matrices, group-theory, quotient-group, modular-group

So far, I know the matrices
$$S=\left( \begin{matrix} 0&-1\\ 1&0 \end{matrix} \right), \quad T=\left( \begin{matrix} 1&1\\ 0&1 \end{matrix} \right) $$
generate SL$(2,\mathbb{Z})$. $S^2=(ST)^3=-I$.

I also know the matrices
$$X=\left( \begin{matrix} 1&1\\ 1&2 \end{matrix} \right), \quad Y=\left( \begin{matrix} 2&1\\ 1&1 \end{matrix} \right) $$
with their inverses $X^{-1},Y^{-1}$ generate SL$(2,\mathbb{Z})'$, the commutator subgroup.

I'm interested in what the quotient $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})'$ is.

In general, how would I go about computing the quotient of two matrix groups? I'm trying to use GAP but I'm having a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 3):

You have the presentation $S^2=(ST)^3=-I$. You get the presentation of $G/G'$ by including
all relations $ST=TS$ etc. So the presentation becomes $S^4=I$, $S^3T^3=S^2$ and $ST=TS$.
This implies $S=T^{-3}$ and $T^{12}=I$. Therefore $G/G'$ is cyclic of order $12$ generated by the image of $T$.

Comment: That calculation shows $G/G’$ is cyclic of order dividing $12$. More work is needed to know $T$ in $G/G’$ has order $12$ rather than order $1, 2, 3, 4$, or $6$.

Comment: The problem here is that $S^2 = (ST)^3 = -I$ is not a group presentation - what does $-I$ mean in this context? It is known that $\langle S,T \mid S^2=(ST)^3, S^4 = 1 \rangle$ is a presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$. The abelianization of that presentation does indeed simplify to $\langle T \mid T^{12}=1 \rangle$, which is a cyclic group of order $12$.